# Golang: Непонятно как отображается текст в консоли

Tags: golang, консоль

Хочу вывести логотип программы ASCII стилем текста, но в консоли все символы смещаются непонятно как и куда, вернее верхушка смещается, а низ остается так как он должен быть, не понимаю почему так..

```
func pLogo() {
    logo := `
    d8888                                         888      
    d88888                                         888      
   d88P888                                         888      
  d88P 888 88888b.d88b.   .d88b.  888d888 88888b.  88888b.  
 d88P  888 888 "888 "88b d88""88b 888P"   888 "88b 888 "88b 
d88P   888 888  888  888 888  888 888     888  888 888  888 
d8888888888 888  888  888 Y88..88P 888     888 d88P 888  888 
d88P     888 888  888  888  "Y88P"  888     88888P"  888  888 
                                          888               
                                          888               
                                          888               
    `
    fmt.Println(logo)
}
```

В чем может быть проблема? **ОС: Windows 10, Shell: cmd.exe**

Comment: Можете для ясности добавить скриншот окна?

Comment: у вас там есть лишние символы. Убрал, проверил, что под Mac os, linux, windows  выдается одна и та же картинка

Comment: @SergeKior оказывается в верхних части был отступ табуляцией, а не пробелами, заменил на пробелы и всё отлично!

Answer (score 1):

В Playground всё нормально показывает https://play.golang.org/p/ynI3ZpNHzyi
На компе тоже нормально, единственное в коде верхняя строка сдвинута, поправил её и всё ок.

Comment: И вправду, оказалось нужно поправить отступы с табуляции на пробелы.